Why does the input event of a number control fire twice when using a Breakpoint?
I have an input type=number control and am listening to its input event. The event is triggering as expected and my event handler is firing as expected as well. However, if and only if I place a breakpoint inside of the event handler and I use the number arrows to change the value, the event handler is getting called twice - When I don't use a breakpoint, the event handler is fired once (as expected).
Why is the event handler firing twice when I place a breakpoint inside of the event handler?


<html>
<body>
    <div>If you place a breakpoint inside of the event handler and then use the arrows to change the number value, you will notice the event handler is fired twice.</div>
    <input type="number" id="numberInput">
    <div id="numberDisplay"></div>

    <script>
        numberInput.addEventListener('input', OnInput_numberInput);

        function OnInput_numberInput(event) {
            // If you place a breakpoint here and use the number arrows to change the value, this handler will fire twice. Otherwise, it fires once as expected.
            numberDisplay.innerHTML = `&nbsp;${event.target.value}&nbsp;`;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>




I suspect it has something to do with the way the console takes keyboard focus when the breakpoint is hit. Does this happen in different browsers?

I've only tested on Edge, Chrome, Brave, and Firefox. It happens on the chromium browsers but does not happen on Firefox.

Then it sounds like a quirk/bug of the Chromium debugger.
